# Powershell retrieve User Login Name, not samAccountname

Tags: powershell, authentication, active-directory, ldap

In the following, I am able to get AD group membership very easily:

```
Get-ADGroupMember -identity "GROUP" | select samaccountname |Export-csv -path "c:\temp\out.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

The output csv is used as an input to another, application that cannot perform LDAP queries securely, so I have to pipe in ACL's via PS. The application, however, depends on the users AD Login Name being case-sensitive. I didn't write the application, so *changing its behavior is not in the cards*. For example, when PS pipes in "bigfoot", user "BigFoot" authenticates as BigFoot, and is denied access. What I need is for PS to pipe in the UPN name part, "BigFoot".

The problem is, some users have a User Login Name that is different from samAccount name, e.g "BigFoot" versus bigfoot. The application will only authenticate using "BigFoot"...in other words, the first part of the UPN.

With Powershell, what AD attribute will return the User Login Name (e.g "BigFoot") and not the samAccountname ("bigfoot")?

Comment: Windows isn't case-sensitive.

Comment: The app, however, is. When a user account is first created in the app, a call to AD retrieves the User Login Name, e.g "BigFoot". However, in order to apply an ACL to a resource in the application, I'm pulling from the list generated by PS, which contains the samAccountname, which, in this case, is "bigfoot". User BigFoot is not granted access to the resource. Due to security issues, the app is not able to directly query AD groups for membership, and modifying the application behavior is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property is called name. In order to retrieve all properties qualify any of the AD cmdlets with -Properties * example Get-AdGroupmember -Properties *

In addition if Get-AdGroupMember does not return a UPN property you might need to make a subsequent call to Get-AdUser example Get-AdGroupMember ABX  | % { Get-AdUser $_ }

Comment: The name property returns, in this case, the full camel case name, e.g "Big Foot", which doesn't work as a login using UPN or WinNT methods. Correct, Get-AdGroupMember will not return UPN (blank output, no errors). Not sure what you mean by piping in the Get-ADUser cmdlet after Get-ADGroupMember......

Answer (score 1):

@Alberto Vargas your solution mostly worked...I had to filter out any nested groups that were within the group I was calling....

```
 Get-ADGroupMember -identity "group"  | Where { $_.objectClass -eq "user" }|%{Get-ADUser $_.SamAccountName | select UserPrincipalName} |Export-c
sv -path "c:\temp\out.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```